# 16.04 LTS wifi doesn't resume after disconnecting from vpn

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, vpn

New to Ubuntu/Linux and running into some issues connecting/disconnecting from vpn. It took me a little while to figure out how to connect to my work network so that I could remote desktop into my workstation. I ended using openconnect to connect to the network and remmina for the actual remote desktop connection (RDC).

The issue I'm running into is after I disconnect from my RDC and openconnect session, the wifi doesn't automatically connect back to my wifi. I usually can see the wifi symbol has full bars, but the internet does not work. At the moment I have just been restarting my computer, but this is obviously not ideal. I couldn't find any threads with similar problems, but if they exist, please direct me to them!

Here is my wifi chip info:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 6b
       serial: 5c:51:4f:ea:45:0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-32-generic firmware=17.459231.0 ip=192.168.168.171 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:46 memory:f1400000-f1401fff
```

Answer (score 1):

Your routing table is the most likely culprit.  It was used to route all your internet packets through your VPN.  There is probably one routing rule to do this and it needs to be replaced.  You will need to open a command line terminal to proceed.  Do the command `ip route show` and look for the rule or rules that begin with *default*.  Enter a rule replacement for that default route rule.  Here is the command that should do it for you: `sudo ip route default via 192.168.168.171 dev wlp2s0`.  Then repeat the command `ip route show` to verify the change.  Verify you can reach the internet with `ping -c 9 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Skaperen,

'sudo ip route default...' isn't a valid command so I ended trying 'sudo ip route add default...'

But then I could not connect to the internet. So now I've deleted that entry.

My default gateway is 192.168.168.1,  and it is set to default:

'default via 192.168.168.1 dev wlp2s0  proto static  metric 600 '

I'm not sure why I would want to change it to '192.168.168.171'. Could you explain why?

Thanks again,

Comment: Just realized that this line shows up in when I run `ip route show` after I disconnect from my vpn: `default dev tun0  scope link `. When I delete this  line with `sudo ip route del default dev tun0 scope link`, my wifi is able to connect again. Thanks! Now I need to figure out how to make this automatic instead manually typing it everytime I use my vpn.

Comment: you could make a script the looks to see if your VPN is down in some obvious way (a program to run it is no longer running) or might be down (your company web site cannot be reached for some decided amount of time) and reset the route in that case.  or you can make a script that explicitly take the VPN down if you do that by command, an reset the route what that script is run.

Comment: your wifi was listed as 192.168.168.171 in your post, but if 192.168.168.1 is your reachable gateway, use that.

Comment: since it sounds like you are running a VPN while at work, you may want to add a 2nd route for your work IPs sending them to the wifi gateway, so you can access work not via the VPN and whatever you are using the VPN for ... at the same time.